# Multiple buffers in shaders in Three.js. WebGL with setRenderTarget instead of renderTarget

Tags: three.js, compilation, buffer, shader

Im trying to understand how to write a shader in three.js with multiple buffers by converting a shader from shaderwith. I found this example:
https://codepen.io/lickedwindows/pen/jGOLJr

But when I run it with the newest version of Three.js I run into the errors:

> "THREE.WebGLRenderer.render(): the renderTarget argument has been
> removed. Use .setRenderTarget() instead."
> "THREE.WebGLRenderer.render(): the forceClear argument has been
> removed. Use .clear() instead."

Im trying to change this but cannot figure out how to do it. How can I change this code into the correct one that compiles with the most recent version of three.js

Basically I want to find a boilerplate for writing multibuffer shaders in three.js

```
//Create 2 buffer textures
textureA = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter });
textureB = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, { minFilter: THREE.LinearFilter, magFilter: THREE.NearestFilter });
```

Answer (score 4):

Your demo uses Three.js r85, which is a bit outdated. As of September 2020, we have r120, and now you have to use `renderer.setRenderTarget(renderT);` each time you want to render to that target. You can read about it in the docs: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderer.setRenderTarget

This is the new approach:

```
var textureA = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
var textureB = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setRenderTarget(textureA);
renderer.render(scene1, camera1);
renderer.setRenderTarget(textureB);
renderer.render(scene2, camera2);
```